# How to tell IDE to type hint a class/instance property correctly?

Tags: ide, code-completion, phpstorm

When declaring a class/instance property, I am accustomed to doing something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
  protected
    /** @var SplDoublyLinkedList */
    $_nodes;
}
```

In the example above, I would expect my IDE (PhpStorm in my case) to show me code completion for the `SplDoublyLinkedList` class any time I typed `$this->_nodes->` anywhere inside the class declaration.

This doesn't appear to be occurring, though.  Is this a a problem with PhpStorm, or am I just not doing it right?

EDIT:  I've submitted a [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7659) on YouTrack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 class MyClass
{
   /** @var SplDoublyLinkedList */
   protected
   $_nodes;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that out this weekend, though it seems like then I'd have to add a visibility operator to every property (e.g., `protected $_nodes; protected $_index;` as opposed to `protected $_nodes, $_index;`, with docblocks inserted in the correct locations).

Comment: You are correct; this is the way that PhpStorm (at least) requires that I annotate my class/instance properties.  I'll have to file an issue on YouTrack (: